# How do I reset skining editing in unity skinning editor(sprite editor)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite

For example, if I messed up and made part of the sprite missing, how do I reset everything, and make it looks as if I never opened skinning editor? In case you don't know, skinning editor is in sprite editor. BTW, I already split the texture and use some sprites in animation, and I don't want to break the link.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is **no such reset button** in the skinning editor. However, you can **delete all the changes that you made before**. If you generated geometry, just go "**Edit Geometry**" button. Then, select all vertex and delete them. And again if you have some bones, go "**Create Bone**" section and delete bones.